# Visual Basic 2010 - new to OO programming, need some guidance on a project

Tags: database, vb.net, oop

I'm new to Visual Basic 2010, but I have some experience of Visual Basic 6. I've been tasked with writing a projects that converts data from two databases. (i.e. customers. contacts, invoices.) What I need to do is convert customers from one database to another and flag any problems (like the address being too long, for example)

I'm new to OO programming so I'm after the best practice to implement this.

Do I setup a customer class that combines the source customer table and destination customer table or separate classes for each please? And where should the methods be placed that does the actual conversion.

Any guidedance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will start programming with VB.NET because you come from vb6.
I recommend you to start reading the Visual Basic .NET Reference before starting

[Reference (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25kad608.aspx)

and this OOP Vb.net Programming guide could help as well:

[Object Oriented Programming In VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8825/Object-Oriented-Programming-In-VB-NET)

Comment: Currently reading Wrox Programming Visual Basic 2010 and .Net 4, I was just after some idea if a Visual Basic 2010 professional was to start this project. There are several ways, like to know the recommended way.

Comment: Ill update muy answer now I'm on cellphone. You have to separate classes in  layers. One for client,  one for logic,another one for data management.etc

Answer (score 0):

I think there are as many ways to go about this as there are programmers around.

If my task was to convert data from one database to another, off the top of my head, I would maybe create a class, for example, called `DBComparer` that would hold, for example the 2 `DataTables` (one from each database) and could have methods to compare the 2 datatables.

I would then inherit that class for each table I needed to convert:

```
Public Class CustomersComparer
    Inherits DBComparer
```

That way you only have one place to change your comparison modules and can use that information for each of your different tables.

Again, this is just an idea and each programmer would give you a different way of doing this - The important part, in my opinion, is to use the AWESOME power .Net offers you through it's wide array of possible objects and true OOP Environment.

Welcome to .Net and I hope this starts your mind working :)